# My function is missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, html, django

I am currently working on my first website, and I'm experiencing some trouble in views.py. Specifically this def:

```
def translated_view(self, request):
    text = request.POST.get('text')
    translate = self.translator
    context = {
        'translated': translate(text)

    }
    return render(request, context, 'main/translated.html')
```

The self is because of this other function that translates text into an invented language.

```
def translator_view(request):
    def translator(phrase):
        translation = ""
        for letter in phrase:
            if letter.lower() in "a":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "U"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "u"
            elif letter.lower() in "t":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "A"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "a"
            elif letter.lower() in "c":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "G"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "g"
            elif letter.lower() in "g":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "C"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "c"
        return translation
    return render(request, 'main/translator.html', { translator : 'translator'})
```

As you can see I have the request argument. However I'm still seeing this error.

Comment: seems like you are using a *function based view*, if so, remove the `self`.

Comment: How is this function being triggered? If it is a simple view function you need to do: `translated_view(request)` - not sure where `self` comes in - is it part of a class?

Comment: Exactly what is the class here? You can not just use `SomeClass.some_method`....

Comment: @ArakkalAbu: that will likely not work, since the `self.translator` indicates there is some class context. But of course that is not how you refer to a method being triggered.

Comment: it is part of another function

Comment: Nitpick: The order of the `render` parameters is also wrong: `return render(request , 'main/translated.html', context)`

Comment: @MarcJuegos_Yt: I think you should include all relevant context. Right now it is impossible to help. Anyway, this is not how you can call a view. Furthermore using a class like this likely makes your view "stateful" which is against the HTTP principles.

Comment: I am doing a translator invented in my own language, so maybe if i put the other function it's more understandable. Now I am going to edit the question in order to include the nested function.

Comment: Are you use class based view?

Comment: def based view.

Comment: I've edited the question, so if you could read the translator function I'd appreciate it.